# Cannot HTTPS POST json object at 1.5 mb via Koa and koa-body. Status 413 production only

Tags: node.js, reactjs, koa, koa-bodyparser

I am attempting to upload a JSON object at about 1.5 mb from our React client to our Koa.js node.js server.

I am using Koa.js with koaBody (koa-body 4.1.1).

On HTTPS, in our production environment, I cannot upload the object, I receive a status of 413 from our server. However, in dev or on http, I have no problem uploading the file. I can change the jsonLimit to '1mb' and replicate the same error in dev, so I know the formatting is correct.

I have setup the configuration to handle up to '10mb'. Here is the code.

```
.use(koaBody({
  multipart: true,
  json: true,
  jsonLimit: "10mb",
}))
```

Does anybody have any solutions?
I will simply split out the JSON object, however I'd like to know 'why' this isn't working, as to me 1.5 mb isn't too large.
[image]

UPDATE: I have set the jsonLimit to '50mg' with no difference in the outcome.

UPDATE: I believe this 413 is related to the ingress controller we have setup via azure.

Comment: Is the object 1.5 Mb or 1.5 MB? 10 Mb = 10/8 MB = 1.25 MB which is not enough if the object is 1.5 MB. Megabytes and megabits are different.

Comment: Looks like `nginx` is in between. Make sure that also the nginx configuration for the body size is large enough - it defaults to 1 MB. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, the body size is indeed around 1.5MB (megabytes), but that's 1.5*8= ~12.5 Mb (megabits). So raise the `jsonLimit` to accomodate for this.

There's also `nginx` between your browser and your application. You'll need to make sure that nginx' body size limit is also high enough. Find `client_max_body_size` in your configurations - or if it doesn't exist, set it for your application (e.g. `client_max_body_size 20m;`

Comment: I did not know I needed to *8. Why is that?
I set the jsonLimit to 50mb, the error still occurs.
This is a kubernetes deployment via docker. Would I be adjusting the nginx config via my cloud service provider?

Comment: One megabyte (MB) is eight megabits (Mb).

Comment: `mb` would be `millibits` ;). However, `koa-body` interpretes `mb` as megabyte. I think the issue is nginx config, especially since this only fails in production where nginx is used.

Comment: This has helped me to look at our ingress controller I setup. This may be the bottleneck right now.

Comment: @GavinThomas If you're using the NGINX Ingress Controller, there appears to be a mechanism to control the configuration via annotations: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size

Comment: While I haven't solved the problem yet, I do believe this is the solution. Thank you for your help! I will update later if it turns out to be something else!